# How to convert java.nio.DirectByteBuffer to java.nio.HeapByteBuffer

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, javafx, amazon-rekognition

I want compare image between source image file

```
InputStream  inputStream;
```

and set to

```
ByteBuffer sourceImageBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream))
```

and source Webcam

```
webcam.getImageBytes()
```

but have problem compare(use AmazonRekognition) between two source

print content

- source InputStream : `java.nio.HeapByteBuffer`
- source webcam : `java.nio.HeapByteBuffer`

How to convert `java.nio.DirectByteBuffer` to `java.nio.HeapByteBuffer` ?

Comment: They’re both ByteBuffer implementations.  Why does it matter whether they’re the same implementation class?

Comment: You can't. You have *what* problem that is leading you on this wild goose chase?